# How to add pictures to RichTextBox in a loop?

Tags: vb.net, image, richtextbox

I am adding different arrays of strings to a RichTextBox and I want to insert pictures too. I searched for a method and they all say Paste it. I tried that but it doesn't work in a loop.

```
Dim df As DataFormats.Format = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap)
for i as integer = 0 to 50
 RTF1.text = RTF1.text & arr1(i) & arr2(i) & vbnewline 
 Dim bmp As New Bitmap(picarr(i))
 Clipboard.SetImage(bmp)
 RTF1.Paste(df)
next i
```

I also tried `SendKeys` because when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it pastes the picture. Also, I tried to exit the loop and it pastes the last image only.

Comment: Note that `Step 1` is redundant. You only need to use `Step` when you want to increment `i` by a number other than 1.

Comment: What is picarr and how is it populated?  Have you verified that is as expected?

Comment: its array of filenames of pictures and yes, it works, because when i press ctrl V, it pastes the image , so its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you set the `RichTextBox.Text` property, you lose all the RTF data it previously contained (including formatting, images, etc.) and you're only maintaining the plain text (because of `= RTF1.Text & ...`).

Instead, use the [`AppendText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext) method like this:

```
Dim df As DataFormats.Format = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap)
For i As Integer = 0 To 50
    RTF1.AppendText(arr1(i) & arr2(i) & vbNewLine)
    Using bmp As New Bitmap(picarr(i))
        Clipboard.SetImage(bmp)
    End Using
    RTF1.Paste(df)
Next
```